# If a moderator deletes the question-OP's comments, the mod is mistakenly marked as OP also

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools

I've seen the screenshots from [this (10k-only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260278) and noticed that when a mod deletes question-OP's comments, the mod's name gets the blue-OP-box too:

> [image]

[Original screenshot there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufx5X.png).

rolfl is certainly not the OP of that question, so their name should be wrapped in the box in such cases.